# How to prove the particular set is not locally path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \subset\mathbb{R}^{2} $ be the subset
$$X=\left\{ \left( x,y\right)  | x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb R\right\} \cup \left\{ (x, 0) \mid x \in \mathbb R \right\}  $$
This subset is path connected, but how can we prove that it's not locally path connected?

---

**Thoughts:** Intuitively I think that given any two points in this set, any path between them has to go via the $x$-axis.

Comment: Are you sure you've defined the set correctly? Do you really mean to say that $x \in \mathbb R$ or $y = 0$? (I would have assumed that we can take $x \in \mathbb R$ as given.)

Comment: Err, what I want to say is that X is the union of the point whose abscissa is rational number and the x-axis

Comment: @woshixiaomao I've edited your post based on your comment. Does this edit capture your intent?

Comment: And then my next question for you is: what you have tried so far? Have you digested the definition of "locally path connected"? Can explain in words/intuition why this space is not locally path connected?

Comment: Your question is a bare problem statement with no context at all, and so may attract down votes and close votes. To avoid this, let me suggest that you look at our suggestions for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [adding context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you for editing, that's right. Then my understanding is that any point x ∈ X has a path connected neighborhood basis. My idea is to take a point and prove that none of its fields are path connected, which may be related to the density of real numbers, but I don't know how to do it specifically.

Comment: @KennyWong Because intuitively I think that any two points in this set, the path between them has to go through the X-axis

Comment: Great. So suppose $x = (0, 1)$ and $U = B(x, \tfrac 1 2) \cap X$ (i.e. the ball of radius $1/2$, centred at $x$). Does there exist an open, path-connected $V$ such that $x \in V \subset U$?

Comment: By the way, I added your thoughts to the body of your question. As Lee says, it's important to share your own thoughts on this site.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the continuous map $f(x,y)=y$. The image of any open set of $(1,0)$ contained $y>0$ is an infinite subset of $\bf Q$, so is not connected. So $(0,1)$ has no connected neighborhood contained in the open set $y>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask if it is (0,1) or (1,0)? Do you use the theorem that the image set of a connected open set under a continuous mapping is connected?

Comment: yes. Edited. thanks